# SQL Server Schema Security

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a user U in a database where I want it to be able to create types and stored procs in a specified schema say UserSchema but not be able to alter schema dbo. So I created the schema and also applied the following grant statement to it:

```
GRANT  ALTER, Execute ON SCHEMA ::UserSchema to [U];
```

When I login as user U and I try create a type in UserSchema it fails with a permissions failure...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does it fail with a message saying "permissions failure", or does it actually include useful information in the error message? Also, have you applied any other permissions to this user?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you also need to grant the `CREATE TYPE` permission on the database to the particular principle(s).

Please see this BOL reference on [CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx):

> Requires CREATE TYPE permission in the current database and ALTER permission on schema_name.

```
grant create type
to [U];
go
```